# Java Servlet: How to instantiate thread and receive messages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, thread-safety

I already read the great article about [Servlet Thread handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading).

I have the following problem: I want to create a simple Servlet that starts either a new Thread that produces in a first version random messages or - depending on the parameter - send a response with all messages that were produced since last request.

I use JQuery AJAX call on browser-site an handled requests with timeouts.

When I run my receiver calls, I get only the first messages that were produced since the thread crashed in the meanwhile. It looks as it would be a thread-safety problem, described in the above-mentioned article, but I can figure it out exactly. 
The log gives me the following information:

```
SEVERE: Exception in thread "Thread-75" 
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.lancom.lsr.util.RandomMessageProducer.run(RandomMessageProducer.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at com.lancom.lsr.util.RandomMessageProducer.run(RandomMessageProducer.java:35)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is my current servlet code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet { 
...
private RandomMessageProducer rmProducer;
private Thread rmpThread; 
...

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<Integer, String> msg = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String sDevs   = request.getParameter("devices");  // Option 1
    String sGetMsg = request.getParameter("rec_msg"); // Option 2
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    // Request: Send information and run thread
    if (sDevs != null && STATUS==0) {                       

       /* Start a dummy producer */             
       rmProducer = new RandomMessageProducer();
       rmpThread = new Thread( rmProducer )
       rmpThread.start();

       pw.print("{\"1\": \"Action started!\"}");
       STATUS=1;
    }
       //  Request: Receive messages
    else if (sGetMsg != null) {
       List<String> logs = rmProducer.getLogMsg();      
       for (String lmsg : logs) {
            // Check if we can update the current Status
           if (msg.equals("<<<FIN_SUCC>>>") || msg.equals("<<<FIN_ERR>>>")) {
               STATUS=0;                    
           }
           msg.put(0, lmsg);
       }
       String json = gson.toJson(msg);      
       pw.print(json);  
   }
   pw.close();
}
}
```

And this is my simple message-producer thread:

```
public class RandomMessageProducer implements Runnable {

    private Queue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedList<String>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 100; ++idx){
          int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
          msgQueue.add("Generated : " + randomInt);
          try {
            wait(500);          
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            msgQueue.add("<<<FIN_ERR>>>");
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        msgQueue.add("<<<FIN_SUCC>>>");
    }

    public List<String> getLogMsg() {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (!msgQueue.isEmpty()) {
            res.add( msgQueue.poll() );
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The requests are performed all 1000ms

Do you probably see my error in reasoning?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is line 35 in RandomMessageProducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have serious thread-safety issues here.

First of all, you're using `wait()` when all you want to do is sleep for a few milliseconds. You should use `Thread.sleep()` instead. That will solve your exception, but won't solve the thread-safety issues.

You have a shared linked list that is used by multiple threads in parallel : the random generator thread stors messages in the queue whild the servlet thread(s) emoved messages from the queue. You should thus either use a concurrent collection (like a ConcurrentLinkedQueue), or synchronize every access to the linked list. I would use a Concurrent collection.

And finally, several servlet threads read and modify the `rmpThread` and `rmProducer` variables in parallel, without any kind of synchronization. The rmpThread variable is written, but never read, so I would make it a local variable instead. To make sure the newly written `rmProducer` is visible by the other servlets, you need to synchronize all its accesses, either by using a synchronized block to write and read it, or by making it `volatile`, or by wrapping it into an AtomicReferece (that's the choice I would make).

So the rmProducer should be declared like this:

```
private AtomicReference<RandomMessageProducer> rmProducerRef = new AtomicReference<>();
```

To modify its value, you should use

```
rmProducerRef.set(rmProducer);
```

And to get it, you shuld use

```
rmProducerRef.get();
```

Comment: Well, I see I have to concern myself with valid thread handling. Thanks for your detailed description!